# How to convert below xaml Programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want format Header like in image (INWARD in First Line, Gross Wt., Pure Wt. & Qty. in Second Line). I can achieve same with following code in XAML, but how can I do this Programmatically?

XAML:

```
   <dg:DataGrid>
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="210">
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                                   Text="INWARD" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center">
                        </TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Width="80"
                                       Text="Gross Weight"
                                       TextAlignment="Right"
                                       Margin="0,0,2,0">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Width="80"
                                       Text="Pure Weight" 
                                       TextAlignment="Right"
                                       Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Width="40"
                                       Text="Quantity"
                                       TextAlignment="Right"
                                       Margin="2,0,0,0">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource grdCellCurrencyData}" 
                                                       Width="80"
                                                       Margin="0,0,2,0">
                            <TextBlock.Text> 
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CurrencyConverter}" ConverterParameter="True">
                                    <Binding Path="INGrossWeight" Mode="OneWay" />
                                    <Binding Path="BaseUOMNoofDecimals" Mode="OneWay" />
                                </MultiBinding> 
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource grdCellCurrencyData}"
                                                           Width="80"
                                                           Margin="0,0,0 0">
                            <TextBlock.Text> 
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CurrencyConverter}" ConverterParameter="True">
                                    <Binding Path="INPureWeight" Mode="OneWay" />
                                    <Binding Path="BaseUOMNoofDecimals" Mode="OneWay" />
                                </MultiBinding> 
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource grdCellCurrencyData}"
                                   Width="40"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=INQuantity, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </dg:DataGrid>
```

In above code if you see in `DataGridTemplateColumn`, I have taken grid inside and split header in two rows. Same way I want to do programmatically from code behind. can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and use [`FrameworkElementFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx) to create the `DataTemplate` for your header programatically, following SO thread is having code related to that - [How do I build a DataTemplate in c# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248362/how-do-i-build-a-datatemplate-in-c-sharp-code/248638#248638)

But, as `FrameworkElementFactory` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091853/purpose-of-using-frameworkelementfactory), it would be better to define header template in `Resources` and use [`FindResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) to set HeaderTemplate.

Edit:

here is your code:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn col1 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

//create the data template 
DataTemplate headerLayout = new DataTemplate();

//set up the stack panel 
FrameworkElementFactory gridFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));

// define grid's rows  
var row1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(RowDefinition));
gridFactory.AppendChild(row1);
var row2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(RowDefinition));
gridFactory.AppendChild(row2);

// set up the inwardTextBlock 
FrameworkElementFactory inwardTextBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
inwardTextBlock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
inwardTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "INWARD");
gridFactory.AppendChild(inwardTextBlock);

//set up the stack panel 
FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
spFactory.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);

// set up the grossWeightTextBlock 
FrameworkElementFactory grossWeightTextBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
inwardTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Gross Weight");
inwardTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.WidthProperty, 80);
spFactory.AppendChild(inwardTextBlock);

// set up the pureWeightTextBlock 
FrameworkElementFactory pureWeightTextBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
inwardTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Pure Weight");
inwardTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.WidthProperty, 80);
spFactory.AppendChild(inwardTextBlock);

// set up the qtyWeightTextBlock 
FrameworkElementFactory qtyWeightTextBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
inwardTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Quantity");
inwardTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.WidthProperty, 80);
spFactory.AppendChild(inwardTextBlock);

gridFactory.AppendChild(spFactory);

// set the visual tree of the data template 
headerLayout.VisualTree = gridFactory;

// set the header template
col1.HeaderTemplate = headerLayout;
```

Comment: i tried to user FrameworkElementFactory but not able to achieve goal. can you provide me sample code for same.