# How to bind to input binding in template programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, code-behind

I need to add a `MouseBinding` to the `InputBindings` of the `ListBoxItems`. I know how to this in xaml.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="MyBorder" ...>
            <Border.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                          Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
            </Border.InputBindings>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

But I need to know how to write the above code in code-behind. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Would you like to get an EventArgs while Clicking on this ListBoxItem?

Comment: I need to bind a Command to the Mouse Click Event of the ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what you might look for! Very nice tutorial here: MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx

Comment: Yes that's a good tutorial but it doesn't explain how to do that for template in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the answer, but if someone finds it, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091989/13179254

As for now, using `FrameworkElementFactory` is not recommended by Microsoft. Use `XAML` instead.

An example:

```xml
<Image.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding
        MouseAction="LeftClick"
        Command="{Binding ClearCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
</Image.InputBindings>
```